# Unable to invoke different page using Response.Redirect("url",false)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to redirect to a different page using `Response.Redirect("url",false)` in asp.net. Can anyone tell me what's gone wrong?

```
Response.Redirect(@"~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx", false);
```

Comment: nothing is wrong with the line of code that you showed

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to enter the url, instead of the filepath. So it should be:

```
Response.Redirect("/Pages/Dashboard.aspx", false);
```

> Redirects a client to a new URL. Specifies the new URL and whether execution of the current page should terminate.

<sup>Like explained here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup>

Comment: I am not able to redirect yet

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Have you tried setting a breakpoint, does it hit?

Comment: There is no much code, and yes the line gets executed successfully.But unable to open on browser.

Comment: Do you get an exception? Can you inspect the response headers with Firebug(Firefox) or Developer tools(Chrome).

Comment: No I dont get any exception. But Headers shows me this exception Headers = 'Response.Headers' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'. But should cause no problem, because on a different page Im having the same redirecting to different page. Even there Headers have same think as I menioned above. Yes that is right @ M4N but Im unable to redirect

Answer (score 1):

As you comment you're using `Response.Headers` your problem isn't actually down to `Response.Redirect`. It's probably down to IIS as `Response.Headers` is only supported in IIS 7.0 running in Integrated Pipeline mode. Also need to be using .NET Framework 3.0 or higher. I imagine that's why you're getting your `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` error

FYI. Response.Redirect is also able to correct just about any path you give it (as long as it's a properly formatted string).

The following will all work:

`Response.Redirect(@"~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx", false);`

`Response.Redirect(@"~\Pages\Dashboard.aspx", false);`

`Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx", false);`